# BuildConfigField to decide how to define the member (enum)

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, android-build, android-buildconfig

build.gradle(Module):

```
productFlavors {
    mytest {
        ...
        buildConfigField "boolean", "SHORT_ENUM", "false"
    }
    mysecondtest {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "SHORT_ENUM", "true"
    }
```

In MyClass I want to define the enum member during the build according to the buildConfigField I've defined:

```
public class MyClass {
    // members initialization
    public enum MYENUM {
        if (BuildConfig.SHORT_ENUM) {
            FIRST(0),
            SECOND(1);
        }
        else { // SHORT_ENUM is false
            FIRST(0),
            SECOND(1),
            THIRD(2),
            FORTH(3);
        }
        private int value;
        MYENUM(int v) {
            value = v;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

But it doesn't work. Is it possible to do what I would like to do? If yes, then how?

Comment: just a question but, based on your example, why not just store it as a boolean ? or are you specifically looking to store and retrieve an enum ?

Comment: But how will I define the enum according to a boolean? Can you please show me?

Comment: If you want dynamic values for enum, you can create generic function which will return the type according this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just write `if` statements in a class definition.

There is no ifdef and ifndef in Java.

What you can do is create the java code folder for each of your product flavors, and then create the enum definition in each of those folders correctly.

example:
app/src/debug/java/my/package/MyEnum.java
app/src/beta/java/my/package/MyEnum.java

Then, when you build debug, it will use the debug version, and if you build beta, it will use the beta version.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `BuildConfig.SHORT_ENUM` is a `boolean`.

Just use

```
if (BuildConfig.SHORT_ENUM){
  ...
}
```

In any case you **can't do** it in this way. 
It depends how you would like to use them. You have many options:

- you can use 2 different classes in the different buildTypes.
- just create a method which will return the values according to the condition

Comment: I editted the question according to your answer but it doesn't compile because I'm using the if(BuildConfig.SHORT_ENUM) during member initialization I guess.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't read well your question. You can't define an enum in this way

Comment: Thanks. So is there no solution? For each project I want to define the member differently. Maybe is there a way to use ifdef and ifndef?